# Prove that the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 - axy \leq 0 \}$ for $a\in [-2,2]$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

I have attempted this question by using the fact that a composition of convex functions is also convex, and we know that $x^2+y^2$ is convex. However, I do not know how to show that $-axy$ is also convex. Do I need to prove it formally using the $\lambda \in [0,1]$ method?

Comment: Use the definition of convexity hello?

Comment: Hi :) level sets of convex functions are convex. Can you prove, that $f(x, y) = x^2+y^2-axy$ is convex for $|a|\leq 2$?

Comment: Can you prove the convexity of $x^2 + y^2 - axy$ by writing $$x^2 + y^2 - axy=\left(x-\frac a2y\right)^2+\frac{4-a^2}4y^2\ \ ?$$ Note that $4-a^2\geq0$.

Comment: @Jochen should i simply find whether the hessian of the function is positive semidefininite/definite ?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2-axy=((1-a/2)(x+y)^2+(1+a/2)(x-y)^2)/2$$
$(x+y)^2$ and $(x-y)^2$ are both squares hence convex, so this is convex if $-2\le a\le 2$ and none of the coefficients are negative.

Proof that any square is convex follows from $(a-b)^2\geq0$ thus $$a^2+b^2\geq2ab\tag{1}$$
so
$$
\begin{align}
((1-t)a+tb)^2
&=(1-t)^2a^2+2t(1-t)ab+t^2b^2\\
&\geq(1-t)^2a^2+t(1-t)(a^2+b^2)+t^2b^2\\
&=(1-t)a^2+tb^2\\
\end{align}
$$
The proof that the sum of two convex function is convex is very obvious.